# How to set firewall for two servers hosted in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have two heroku apps accessing the same Redis database. I need to make sure only these two servers can access it.

Normally, I can do this by setting firewall through IP. However, Heroku uses dyno system, and does not have fixed IP for servers.

I found `proximo` addon, which can be used to set an IP for each of my apps. But I would like to know if there is a simpler solution for this issue.

Comment: Why not set a password for redis? http://redis.io/commands/auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any control or guarantee about the servers running your application on Heroku or their IP addresses.

You should use a secondary authentication mechanism, like redis's built in auth scheme for connections to authenticate the incoming request.

This is the mechanism most of the hosted redis providers on Heroku use (RedisToGo, OpenRedis, etc).